# What is the lowermost energy a photon can be emitted by hyperfine transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

The 21 centimeter Hydrogen line comes from the hyperfine transition from its one electron, which leads to a photon with the energy of $2.24\times10^{-25}$ joules being emitted.

Can lower energy levels be achieved by any other hyperfine transition?

Comment: Unless there's a limit to the definition of 'hyperfine transitions,' one could imagine transitions in element 111 of rather low energy.

Comment: If I may ask, what is your reasoning to achieve this conclusion?

Comment: the more electrons there are, the more levels and interacting levels, etc.

Comment: I get 9.5E-25 Joules, BTW, via  https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/photon-energy

Comment: Thanks for the observation on the energy level. An oversight by my part, was doing calculations for other frequencies and got them mixed up.